# SQL Command to show no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to answer this question:
Which are the top 10 states with the most Medicare Payment in 2014? 
This is what I have so far:

[image]

I am trying to get rid of the duplicate States. There should be 10 different states that have the highest Medicare Payment.

Comment: But why do you have duplicates?  Of the multiple CA records, which one do you need?

Comment: Are you sure you use MySQL? (Since MySQL doesn't support TOP.)

Comment: No my first time here and accidentally tagged it. I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I suggest you look at your data first - I suspect the data in the table is incorrect.

Comment: Define "duplicate" as you perceive it in your table.

Comment: Like @AleksG said, there's probably something wrong with your data

Comment: As I understand it, you want only one row per state? Which one?

Comment: The duplicates are there because there is also Provider City. Like,  Los Angles, CA and San Fransisco, CA

Comment: How would I check my data? I am pretty new to using SQL

Comment: Add some sample table data, with several CA rows, and show us the expected result. All as well formatted text.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - `SUM`ing values that are averages tends to be meaningless since you've lost the individual population counts from which each average was derived.

Comment: Thank you Damien, the command you provided me gave me the exact result I needed.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you want the "highest" average per state to be the defining characteristic for the ordering.

We can do that by constructing a CTE or subquery that runs a `GROUP BY` and aggregate to reduce each state to a single row, before attempting to find the top 10:

```
;With Highest as (
    select [Provider State],MAX([Average Medicare Payments]) as Medicare
    from [Medicare_InPatient_2014]
    group by [Provider State]
)
select top 10 *
from Highest
order by Medicare desc
```